# Concatenating two pre-trained BERT

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, bert-language-model

```
max_length = 50
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-large', do_lower_case=True)
encodings = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(comments,max_length=max_length,pad_to_max_length=True, truncation=True) # tokenizer's encoding method
train_inputs = encodings['input_ids']
train_masks = encodings['attention_mask']
train_inputs = torch.tensor(train_inputs)
train_labels = torch.tensor(train_labels)
train_masks = torch.tensor(train_masks)
batch_size = 48
train_data = TensorDataset(train_inputs, train_masks, train_labels)
train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_data)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('roberta-large', num_labels=num_labels)
model.cuda()
```

Hi, i'm using HuggingFace library for classification, i want to concatenate two types of BERT together. this is not the entire code. i just want you to know how i've used tokenizer and encodings. now i have 2 questions:

1: how can i see the created vectors? it's dimension and the vector it self. 2: in which step should i concatenate two BERT together? their vectors? or their output (logit) maybe?